# OpenCV : Assertion failed using one of the two constructors of SIFT

Tags: c++, opencv, sift

I'm trying to use Sift but i have an error. I don't understand why.

I do something like that :

```
detector = new SiftFeatureDetector(0.03,//feature threshold
                                 10);//threshold to reduce sensitivity to lines,
SiftDescriptorExtractor extractor;
```

Then i get this error :

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (firstOctave >= -1 && actualNLayers <= nOctaveLayers) in operator(), file terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'  
what():  /home/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/nonfree/src/sift.cpp:755: error: (-215) firstOctave >= -1 && actualNLayers <= nOctaveLayers in function operator()
```

Howewer when i used SIFT with this way for example :

```
detector = new SiftFeatureDetector(400)
```

it works ! But I don't know what is this parameter, because on the documentation this is something like that :

```
SiftFeatureDetector( double threshold, double edgeThreshold,...)
```

Can you explain me please and tell me what i did wrong? Thank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the exception log you are working with OpenCV 2.4.6.1.

That said you are probably referring to the documentation of a **former OpenCV release**. As you can see below, the constructor has been modified between 2.3.0 and 2.4.0:

**[OpenCV 2.3.0](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/b1459928f576c36e8857bac987c49a0c84d77656/modules/features2d/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp#L1506-L1510)**

```
SiftFeatureDetector( double threshold, double edgeThreshold, ... );
```

**[OpenCV 2.4.0](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/ea3fe441df5e874b229f7fafa2bc8042f97b97dc/modules/nonfree/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp#L61-L63)**

```
explicit SIFT( int _nfeatures=0, int _nOctaveLayers=3,
          double _contrastThreshold=0.04, double _edgeThreshold=10,
          double _sigma=1.6);

// ...

typedef SIFT SiftFeatureDetector;
typedef SIFT SiftDescriptorExtractor;
```

So in your case you pass wrong parameters, which should explain the abnormal situation.

Comment: I got it ! I didn't see that ! Thank you !